# Undefined output (K&R 1.19)

Tags: c, output

i'm trying to figure out exercise 1.19 of K&R.

> Write a function reverse(s) that reverses the characte string s. 
>      Use it to write a program that reverses its input a line at a time

Here is my code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 150

void reverse(char s[]);

int main()
{
    int c, i;
    char string[MAX];

    i=0;
    while((c=getchar())!= EOF){
       while((c=getchar()) != '\n'){
            string[i] = c;
            i++;
       }
       reverse(string);
    }
    return 0;
}
void reverse(char s[]){
   int i, j;
   for(i=0; i<MAX-1; i++){
       if(s[i] == '\n')
          break;
   }
   for(j=i;j>=0;j--)
     printf("%c", s[j]);
   printf("\n");

}
```

The problem is that i have an undefined output, like this
[image: Undefined Behavior]

I tryied to figure it out, but doesn't make sense to me.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: "Write a function reverse(s) that reverses the character string s. 
   Use it to write a program that reverses its input a line at a time"

Comment: C strings are nullterminated... Your program will always go over the entire length of the buffer without looking at the actual length of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code.

First you "swallow" the first character with your EOF check; the first which gets written to the array is actually the second (if you typed `string^ it would copy`tring` to the buffer).

Then you reverse the full buffer (150 characters) regardless of the length of the string contained. The garbage you see is just the "rest" of the buffer which you also reverse. Note the last characters of the "garbage" is `gnirt`, which is `tring` reversed.

Then also pay attention to proper string termination with `\0`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to instead of these loops -

```
while((c=getchar())!= EOF){
   while((c=getchar()) != '\n'){
```

Try this -

```
 while((c=getchar()) != '\n' && c!=EOF){
```

And after this loop before calling function -

```
string[i]='\0';   // append '\0'
```

And in function `reverse` instead of checking for `'\n'` check for `'\0'` -

```
for(i=0; s[i]!='\0'; i++){      //you use it to get length of string
}
 /* Or better to get length use strlen() from <string.h>   */
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
while((c=getchar())!= EOF){
   while((c=getchar()) != '\n'){
        string[i] = c;
        i++;
   }
```

with:

```
while(((c=getchar())!= EOF) && (c != '\n')){
        string[i] = c;
        i++;
        string[i] = '\0'
   }
```

Comment: First, you need a zero terminator. Second, you don't need a nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_ARRAY_SIZE 50

void Reverse(char string[]);

void Reverse(char string[])
{
    int stringSize = 0;
```

i use a while loop to iterate through the string array and calculate its length

```
    while (string[stringSize] != '\0')
    {
        stringSize++;
    }

    int  i = 0;
```

I de-increment stringSize so when it gets printed out at the end it doesn't include the NULL terminator character ('\0')

```
    stringSize -= 1;

    for (i = stringSize; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%c", string[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int c = 0;

    char string[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE];
```

Checks whether getchar is EOF or c is a newline character ('\n')

```
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
        string[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
```

Sets string[i] to a null line character so it doesn't print out the whole array in reverse just the part that contains the string

```
    string[i] = '\0';

    Reverse(string);

    return 0;
}
```